# Shared Preference not working

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-volley

I am trying to do multiple requests and I am saving data in shared preference the second shared preference code:

```
public void makeMultipleRequests()

{
    for(i=0;i<districtid.length;i++)
    {
        districtId=districtid[i];
    String  url="http://49.50.72.188/epdswebsite/webservice.asmx/GetDFSCDetails?DistrictId="+districtId;
         dfsc = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                dialog.dismiss();
                try {
                    if (dialog.isShowing()){
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                    JSONArray ar = response.getJSONArray("DFSCDetails");
                    JSONObject data= ar.getJSONObject(0);
                    String ema=data.getString("Email");
                    String mob=data.getString("Mobile");
                    String off= data.getString("LandLine");
                    String ser= data.getString("DFSCName");
                    String tit = data.getString("District_Name");
                    String add=data.getString("Address");
                    String disid= data.getString("District_Number");
                    preference = getSharedPreferences("Dfsc"+disid, 0);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = preference.edit();
                    edit.putBoolean("dfscboolean", true);
                    edit.putString("serial", ser);
                    edit.putString("office", off);
                    edit.putString("title", tit);
                    edit.putString("address", add);
                    edit.putString("mobile", mob);
                    edit.putString("email", ema);
                                        edit.apply();
                                        dialog.dismiss();

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }}
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                dialog.dismiss();
            }

        });
        String surl="http://49.50.72.188/epdswebsite/webservice.asmx/GetFSODetailByDistrict?DistrictId="+districtId;
         JsonObjectRequest fso= new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, surl, null, new Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    try {
                        JSONArray ar = response.getJSONArray("FSOModelDetails");
                        JSONObject data= ar.getJSONObject(0);
                        String add= data.getString("Office_Address");
                        String mob= data.getString("Personal_Mobile");
                        String nam = data.getString("Name");
                        String dis = data.getString("District_Name");

                        SharedPreferences  mPrefs = getSharedPreferences("Fso"+districtId, 0);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = mPrefs.edit();
                        edit.putBoolean("fsoboolean", true);
                        edit.putString("address", add);
                        edit.putString("mobile",mob);
                        edit.putString("name", nam);
                        edit.putString("district", dis);

                            edit.apply();
                            System.out.println(mPrefs.getString("address", "failed"));
                            dialog.dismiss();

                        dialog.dismiss();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed! Could not connect to the server!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    dialog.dismiss();   
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed! Could not connect to the server!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            });
         request.add(dfsc);
         request.add(fso);
    }
    `*
```

This is the second activity where I am fetching the data from`enter code here` shared preference:

```
public void loadstaticdata()
{
    SharedPreferences mPrefs = getSharedPreferences("Fso"+districtId, 0);
    String addres=mPrefs.getString("address", "");
    String nam=mPrefs.getString("name", "");
    String distric=mPrefs.getString("district", "");
    String mobil=mPrefs.getString("mobile", "");
    System.out.println(addres);
    System.out.println(distric);
    System.out.println(mobil);
    System.out.println(nam);
    address.setText(addres);
    name.setText(nam);
    district.setText(distric);
    mobile.setText(mobil);

}
```

*Where am I wrong?*

Comment: yes i am not able to get data in loadstaticdata()
{
}

Comment: try edit.commit() instead of edit.apply().. It may not change but just a try

Comment: I think that [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34221737/4871526) can help you!

Comment: I am facing a problem where i cant acces the Shared Preference or you can say I cannot insert values into the Shared Preference

Comment: are you sure json return vales is not empty? you print it in log cat?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should choose a method like `SQLite` if you're going to save a significant amount of data.

Anyway, since you're using this on your project, I thought to give a direct answer to your question.

Instead of `edit.apply();` try using `edit.commit();`.

The `commit()` method runs on the main thread and would block. The `apply()` method runs asynchronously.

Comment: The same method is working for Dfsc Request but not for the other one

Comment: Are you sure that there is no exception occurring and that the data which you write is not empty?

Comment: No the data is not empty

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the SharedPreferences is an insensate from `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences`

To commit any data:

```
    String myValue="My Value";
    SharedPreferences preference = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = preference.edit();
    edit.putString("KEY", myValue);
    /*  Your Code  */
    edit.commit();
```

To retrieve it:

```
    SharedPreferences mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String myValue=mPrefs.getString("KEY", "");
    /* Your code */
```

Comment: That really should not be necessary. I've never used getDefaultSharedPreferences and it always works fine

Comment: It worked but since i am using it in a loop it is only giving me the last value .....any solution for that ?

Comment: @RohitSharma because it's override the value each time, so there is a trick by adding an ID for each key, ex; `edit.putString("serial"+disid, ser);`