# How to save UserID in SharedPreferences and retrieve for login?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

When a user logs into my app it returns a userID. This userID is then passed to another activity using intents and should be saved in `SharedPreferences` for next usage in taosts etc.

When the user tries to login again, and if he is already logged in, then it should redirect to the next activity. In this activity, I won't have any userID from the login process and in that case, it should get that value from the `SharedPreferences`.

How to use `SharedPreferences` for this?

Here is some code

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);

Intent i = getIntent();
userid = i.getStringExtra("userid");

 if(userid!= null){
     final SharedPreferences saveid = 
         getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(userid, 0);
 }

Toast.makeText(this, userid, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: I think that this answer can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34221737/4871526

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if(userid!= null){

  SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
  editor.putString("KEY", String.valueOf(userid));
  editor.apply();
}
```

and for checking already having login user id

```
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
    String value = sharedPreferences.getString("KEY", "");

    if (value.equals("")) {
      // not having user id
    } else {
      // user id is available 
    }
```